# Are the sentences correct grammatically?

Tags: prepositions

Are the sentences correct grammatically?

> 1: What may be the disease she is suffering?
> 2: What may be the disease she is suffering from?

Comment: We usually speak of 'suffering from a disease'.

Comment: Jai, I have a feeling you're asking about whether to use "suffering" or "suffering from". If that's your question, please use the small "Edit" button under your question and make it clear that that's your question. Simply asking if two sentences are grammatically correct is off-topic for this site

Answer (score 0):

Sentence 1 is incorrect; the preposition "from" is necessary to clarify the relationship between "disease" and "suffering." Sentence 2 is technically grammatically correct, but is not very idiomatic and would rarely ever be seen. A more intuitive word order might look something like this:

> What disease might she be suffering from?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct. 'What may be the disease she is suffering **from**?'

We can also say, 'What disease is she suffering from?' or  'What disease may she be suffering from?'

He is suffering from cancer.